# replace values in dataframe based on indexes on second dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, replace

I have the following task: replace values of variable V1 in dataframe A with values fo the same variable in dataframe B. Next I simulate the dataframes:

```
set.seed(123)

A<-data.frame(id1=sample(1:10,10),id2=sample(1:10,10),V1=rnorm(10),V2=rnorm(10))
###create dataframe B
B<-A[sample(1:10,5),1:3]
###change values to be updated in df A
B$V1<-rnorm(5)
###create a row which is not in A, to make it more interesting
B<-rbind(B,c(11,12,rnorm(1)))
```

Now I provide a non optimal solution which I wish to make more cleaner

```
temp<-left_join(A,B,by=c("id1","id2"))
temp[!is.na(temp$V1.y),"V1.x"]<-temp[!is.na(temp$V1.y),"V1.y"]

A<-temp[,setdiff(colnames(temp),"V1.y")]
colnames(A)[colnames(A) %in% "V1.x"]<-"V1"
```

It would be desirable to avoid creating temporal objects and modify directly df A. Also the solution should be scalable to replace values in more than one column of A. I am think in something like

```
A[expression1,desired_cols]<-B[expression2,desired_cols]
```

where `expression1` and `expression2` are inteded to match indexes in both df and `desired_cols` are the names of columns to be replaced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a join from `data.table` and update the columns of 'A' with the corresponding `i.` column of the second dataset ('B')

```
library(data.table)
setDT(A)[B,  V1 := i.V1, on = .(id1, id2)]
```

If we are replacing multiple columns, make note of the columns to replace

```
nm1 <- names(A)[3:4]
nm2 <- paste0("i.", nm1)
setDT(A)[B, (nm1) := mget(nm2), on = .(id1, id2)]
```

---

Or if we use `left_join`, then `coalesce` would be better

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(A, B, by = c('id1', 'id2')) %>%
        transmute(id1, id2, V1 = coalesce(V1.y, V1.x), V2)
```

Comment: it is scalable to replacing in multiple columns??

Comment: @NicolasMolano Yes, you can do `setDT(A)[, B, names(A)[3:4] := mget(paste0("i.", names(A)[3:4])), on = .(id1, id2)]`

Comment: it seems that this task canont be done with base R using something like A[expression1,desired_cols]<-B[expression2,desired_cols]?

Comment: @NicolasMolano. It can be done with `base R`. as well.  Just need. a simple tweak to your code i.e. instead of selecting single column name on the `j`, sellect multiple columns